# Corrupted Navigation Views

Tags: list, swiftui, navigationview

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in SwiftUI, but I wondered if anyone has encountered it and figured out a workaround.  My normal use case is to have a search field appear, but I've simplified it to the point where a simple text string exhibits the bug.

Create a single-view app, copy this into ContentView, and run it. Tap the search icon twice, then scroll the view; you'll see the text scrolling UNDER the title.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  private var items = (0 ... 50).map {String($0)}
  @State private var condition = false

  var searchButton: some View {
    Button(action: {self.condition.toggle()}) {
      Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").imageScale(.large)
    }
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      VStack {
        if condition {
          Text("Peekaboo")
        }

        List {
          ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
            HStack {
              Text(item)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("List of Items")
      .navigationBarItems(leading: searchButton)
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Title overlaps list items]
[image: This is what the suggested solution looks like.]
[image: Blank text view in else clause]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bug, submit feedback to Apple, but currently this is how `NavigationView` behaves - it collapses navigation bar *only* if its top content is `List/ScrollView/Form`. So to solve the issue move your `VStack` either into a `List` or out of `NavigationView`

1)

```
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
          if condition {
             Text("Peekaboo")
          }
          ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
```

2)

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
         if condition {
            Text("Peekaboo")
         }
         NavigationView {
           List {
```

Comment: I've tried a lot of combinations, including that one, but this one does not work either. True, the list no longer goes fully behind the title, but it puts the text ABOVE the nav buttons (it should be below them), and the List title is still drawn incorrectly, only now it overlaps the first element in the list. I have a screenshot; I'll add it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a View cannot cope with variable number of views.
A workaround this strange behavior is this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
private var items = (0 ... 50).map {String($0)}
@State private var condition = false

var searchButton: some View {
Button(action: {self.condition.toggle()}) {
  Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass").imageScale(.large)
}
}

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            if condition {
                Text("Peekaboo")
            } else {
                Text("")
            }
           // or use this  Text(condition ? "Peekaboo" : "")
            List {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) {item in
                    HStack {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("List of Items")
        .navigationBarItems(leading: searchButton)
    }
}
}
```

Let me know if it works, if not let us know what device/system you are using. Tested with Xcode 11.6 beta, Mac 10.15.5, target ios 13.5 and mac catalyst.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't work either. The thing I'm materializing is not text, but a search textfield; the text was just for this example. By the theory that the problem is that the number of child views is variable, just wrapping the conditional text in a Group would make the count constant, but that doesn't work either. I'm using the Xcode beta and 13.6 iOS; haven't tried it on Catalyst.

Comment: Follow-up: adding else {Text("")} does stop the scrolling-behind rendering glitch, but instead scrolling leaves a blank space where the large title used to be. I'm adding a screenshot with the space marked in red.

Comment: If anyone from Apple reads this question, I filed feedback FB7739422 and FB7743113 about this.

Comment: I'm glad you have actually tried it. To fix the blank space, instead of Text(""), you could use EmptyView().

Comment: I tried EmptyView() first; that didn't work either. It devolves to the original behavior of scrolling the list behind the title. I think it's because the "compiled" view representation elides empty views.